# Scaping subfolders with desktop version of Outwit Hub Pro

Tags: https, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape subfolders in the form of tabs on the product URL below. I placed the markers before and after, as is needed in the desktop version of outwit hub pro, but nothing happens when I scrape the two URLs (*Features & Techdata*) in the fast scape option.

The URLs are as follows

[Product URL](https://www.us.hilti.com/drilling-%26-demolition/rotary-hammers/r3683)

[Features Tab URL](https://www.us.hilti.com/drilling-%26-demolition/rotary-hammers/r3683#!folder-features)

[Techdata Tab URL](https://www.us.hilti.com/drilling-%26-demolition/rotary-hammers/r3683#!folder-techdata)

Am I missing something or is the program unable to scrape sub folders in a secure protocol?

Comment: The tabs are loaded via ajax returning html. I don't know anything about this program, but https://www.google.com/#q=outwit+ajax should give you some answers.

Answer (score 0):

I have the solution. I used Firebug, as I am using Firefox.
What I did was the following:

- Went to NET tab in Firebug then the XHR tab.
- Clicked on the tab ‘*Features & Application*’ (*the tab that I wanted
  to scrape*).
- Which then turned up the AJAX request URL.

Used the marker before and after as normal, then applied the **scraper** to the URL that was shown in the XHR tab.

**@ Arthur** *: Thank you for your input Arthur I truly appreciate it! May you also find many that people that can help you on your path.*